# Who is the red woman in .hack//SIGN's opening?

Tags: .hack

In the opening of .hack//SIGN there is a woman who looks to be wearing a red body suit and a visor, at the end she's seen floating on the opposite side of the screen to where Aura is but she is never seen in .hack//SIGN

I am wondering, is this woman what Morganna Mode Gone would look like if she had a PC Body or is she some other Player/AI

Comment: In the .hack//GIFT opening, that woman in red turns into [Helba](http://dothack.wikia.com/wiki/Helba).